# uwp app name not found in current context

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, packaging, uwp-xaml

my UWP app has min version of **anniversary update and target is creators update**. Some name properties of XAML elements give **compile time errors** on some pages and then when I remove the name properties from XAML and then rewrite the same properties there the error goes away and my app runs fine.

I can handle this strange scenario in **debugging** this way but now I am trying to create my **app packages** and only 1 package is created and then some error like this comes up, I fix them by rewriting the name properties and then I try again, and next time some other name properties show the error, and it is an endless loop and I am not able to create 3 packages for **86, 64 and ARM**. only 86 is created and then some error shows up.

**UPDATE**

I am having following problem after I removed "creators fall update sdk preview" from target version of my project and I targeted my project to creators update SDK, while min version remains to anniversary update. I had to do it because on developer store, when I uploaded my created packages, they gave me error that some Mir.px something file is unsupported version, i.e : 16190 ( creators fal update sdk). So I tried to re target my project to creators update and then again created the packages and had the following errors.

[image]

Also note that I removed Threading.Tasks.Extensions package from my project to remove these warnings, ( because I wasn't using it anyway ) but these warnings still didn't go away.

Comment: Try deleting `Obj` and `bin` folders under your projects and then try compiling.

Comment: already tried that, that aint working

Comment: What do you mean by rewriting the name properties?

Comment: Name="xxxx"
this is name property in XAML, I cut this property then save the file then paste it again at the same place then save the file again

Comment: I have tried creating packages with a blank app and it was successful, I was able to create all 3 packages. I also tried to create only x86 package for my project and it was sucesful after 2 attempts, but then I tried to make only x64 but it failed.

Comment: I have also noticed that most of the errors are when I am using user controls which I created myself, and also one third party user control which I am using. but they all work fine after I do the cut paste trick, the only problem occurring is when I try to create the appbundle with all 3 forms, x86, 64 and ARM

Comment: Don't use `Name`. Always use `x:Name`. Also, you should @ me otherwise I won't get notified.

Comment: @JustinXL Please add this as an answer so that I can mark it as selected  answer :)

Comment: @JustinXL Please see the update version of the question I am having another trouble while creating app packages.

Comment: Could you please post a different question on this? It looks like a completely different issue here.

Comment: @JustinXL here is the link of the new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45272582/uwp-app-bundle-creation-failed-catastrophic-error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend to always use `x:Name` over `Name` in XAML.

> The specified x:Name becomes the name of a field that is created in
>   the underlying code when XAML is processed, and that field holds a
>   reference to the object. The process of creating this field is
>   performed by the **MSBuild** target steps, which also are responsible for
>   joining the partial classes for a XAML file and its code-behind.

More info can be read from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-name-attribute).