# uwp app bundle creation failed catastrophic error

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, packaging, uwp-xaml

I am having following problem after I removed "creators fall update sdk preview" from target version of my project and I targeted my project to creators update SDK, while min version remains to anniversary update. I had to do it because on developer store, when I uploaded my created packages, they gave me error that some Mir.px something file is unsupported version, i.e : 16190 ( creators fal update sdk). So I tried to re target my project to creators update and then again created the packages and had the following errors.

[image]

Also note that I removed Threading.Tasks.Extensions package from my project to remove these warnings, ( because I wasn't using it anyway ) but these warnings still didn't go away.

**update**

tried to update the UniversalWindowsPlatform Package and got following error

> Failed to download package 'Microsoft.Net.Native.SharedLibrary-x64.1.6.1' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.net.native.sharedlibrary-x64/1.6.1/microsoft.net.native.sharedlibrary-x64.1.6.1.nupkg'.
>   The HTTP request to 'GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.net.native.sharedlibrary-x64/1.6.1/microsoft.net.native.sharedlibrary-x64.1.6.1.nupkg' has timed out after 100000ms.
>     GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.net.native.sharedlibrary-x64/1.6.1/microsoft.net.native.sharedlibrary-x64.1.6.1.nupkg

Comment: ok let me try that, and just another question, I am on insider build 16193 , is that a possible reason for the problem ?

Comment: I tried to update universalwindowsplatform package and I got an error of timed out please the the update part of question.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44027526/unable-to-load-package-microsoft-net-native-sharedlibrary-x64)\?

Comment: just saw this and tried to install nugget CLI, when I run the nugget.exe it just blinks and never stays running

Comment: No actually its my personal laptop on which I work

Comment: In that link the second answer tells you how to download n manually put it in the global folder.

Comment: yes but they are also using nugget CLI after they download the package itself to put it in global folder

Comment: Not sure. Try to see if you can ping Nuget website, also see if you can download  any other packages.

Comment: yes I am able to download and update other packages properly

Comment: Strange. Consider submitting an issue [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corert/issues).

Comment: I was able to update the package on one of my virtual machines, so it seems like there is some problem only specific to this package on my network/firewall

Comment: @JustinXL  after that rebuild was succesfull but then I again tried to create packages and got the same type of errors as I already mentioned in the screenshot above.

Comment: Might have something to do with your insider build I think. You should always create packages in a rtm build.

Comment: actually my virtual machine is rtm build anniversary update, and its not an insider build, but my project targets creators sdk, can that be a problem?

Comment: Yes... You will need creators on that I think.

Comment: ok will try that

Comment: @JustinXL I even tried creators update on one of my virtual machines and tried to develop packages there i am getting same error,but when I change the target app version to 16190 ( creators fall update preview SDK ) then I can succesfully create app packages. but those packages can't be uploaded on store I dont understand, I already see apps who are using fluent design which is part of preview SDK, why am I not able to upload those packages created from preview SDK?

Comment: You can use composition API in CU. It's hard to check your issue without seeing the project. Consider uploading it to GitHub.

Comment: Ok ill try to create a minimal project which produces the error and then ill upload it to github

Comment: @JustinXL Please have a look, in this repo ive put minimal project of my app which causes the error on package building. Note that this project was created with windows template studio. I created the project and then only made some changes in package manifest and used asset generator for assets. Thats all I changed. and before I made these 2 changes this sample project was producing app packages succesfully. after these 2 changes it gave the error. but I made same changes in blank app project manifest but that didnt give any error.
https://github.com/touseefbsb/BundleCreationFailed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150145/discussion-between-justin-xl-and-touseef).